# Android Studio - convert emojis to string

Tags: java, android, string, char, emoji

I am programming an android application which makes entries in a mysql-database. An other system, which reads from the db, can display the emojis, but only when they are witten-out as string. 
That means when I use the emoji grinning face I get two characters: '\uD83D' and '\uDE00'. In my DB I want to display the string "\uD83D\uDE00". I do not have emojis exclusively. So I have to recognize if the char is an emoji or not.

I am using an android Edittext, if this does matter.

Comment: The Question is not clear, what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I need a function, what makes me this char to a string

Comment: Here´s an [emoji-keyboard](https://github.com/erikswed/emoji-keyboard) you can check out for how to handle the emoji AND plane text. Especially the [EmojiTextView](https://github.com/erikswed/emoji-keyboard/blob/master/emoji-library/src/main/java/com/gotcreations/emojilibrary/model/layout/EmojiTextView.java)